# Distribute Spacing not working as it should

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distribute

i have these grouped objects in Illustrator and i want to vertically distribute the space between them.
It used to work but maybe i did something wrong that i don't know of
[image: grouped products]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is each row grouped together or is each box/title/table grouped individually?

Comment: Honestly if you use AI for this, you are taking the hard route. This is exactly where InDesign is superior, faster and more consistent than AI.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the middle row....

[image]

There are clearly duplicate boxes, and type behind the boxes... this indicates things are **not** grouped properly before distributing.

You need to...

1. Group *each* box and the table below it.
2. Then Group all 3 boxes/tables in *each* row.
3. *Then* distributing space vertically should work as expected.

You should have 4 groups... then *inside* each of those 4 "main" groups, 3 more groups. For a total of 16 groups in all.

It *looks* like the middle 2 rows were **not** grouped properly before distributing. Ungrouped object are all treated as *independent* objects when distributing. Illustrator isn't smart enough to understand any *visual* separation or correlation between objects. Which is why grouping becomes important.

<sub>(For the record, I do agree with comments under the question. This is where InDesign would make this much, much faster and easier. In addition to making any future editing *much* simpler.)</sub>

Comment: i do "place" them in indesign after i arrange them Scott, the .pdf layouts are generated by an online warehouse software (by groups and size), i only use this so i don't have to manually add 11000 products

Answer (score 0):

So i found a way, the problem was with the document. Saved it as an .ai (because it was an imported .pdf) closed the document and reopened it and after that i only needed to group them by row, now distribute spacing works like a charm